# Apache Features URL linked to my site

Tags: apache, seo, google-search-console

i deployed my site in a server which runs apache2 in debian 8 linux distro.

Now, Google Search Console says that there are 2 **crowl errors** resulting in **404**:

1. https://www.tapparellefaidate.it/manual/en/ru/new_features_2_0.html - linked from https://www.tapparellefaidate.it/manual/en/new_features_2_0.html
2. https://www.tapparellefaidate.it/manual/en/mod/mod_example.html

Searching this URLs in Google i notice that several sites are affected by this strange behavior. For example:

- http://doppiovetro.it/manual/ru/mod/mod_example.html
- https://coachingattitudes.com/manual/en/new_features_2_0.html
- http://blaircourtequineclinic.co.uk/manual/en/new_features_2_0.html
- http://www.crm.imasweb.it/manual/en/new_features_2_0.html
- https://w.feenstra.com/manual/en/new_features_2_0.html
- etc...

Where Google found this links and how i can remove them?
There's some apache configuration or Virtual Host error?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Antonio